# How to get last 5 minutes of data with datetime data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I would like to run a query against data that is being consumed by an Esri ArcGIS Server SQL Server database, the data reads as `4/15/2015 4:21:45 PM`  when I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM ServiceRequest.DBO.History_Table 
WHERE: Time = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

I return all records with today's date, but how would I extend this so that I retrieve the last 5 minutes? My `History_Table` column is a `date` data type.

Comment: if it is a `date` type then it has no time portion. Are you sure it isn't a `datetime` or `datetime2` ? If it has no time portion then the question of "last five minutes" is not queryable.

Comment: My apologies it's a `date` datatype in ArcGIS which can be used as `DATETIME2(n), DATETIME, SMALLDATETIME` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 15):

You should query from the parameter less five minutes using the `DATEADD` function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Then use the minutes parameter

```
WHERE [dateColumn] > DATEADD(minute, -5,  GETUTCDATE())
```